# How to integrate Twitter Bootstrap into Backbone app

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

So I have the following index.html:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Project</title>
  ￼ <link href="public/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="lib/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="public/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

**main.js**

```
  (function($){
         // Object declarations goes here
        var FormLoanView = Backbone.View.extend({
          tagName: 'div',
          template: _.template('<p class="text-uppercase">Uppercased text.</p>'),
          initialize: function(){
            var data = this.$el.html(this.template())
            $('body').html(data)
          }
        })


         $(document).ready(function () {

          var LoanView = new FormLoanView({
          });

        });
       })(jQuery);
```

I am trying to create `<p class="text-uppercase">Uppercased text.</p>` and append it to the body in my `index.html`. It does return the `p` element, but the  bootstrap styles don't kick in because "Uppercased text." does not return with uppercase letters. Anyone know why this is happening? Can bootstrap classes not be using in `_.template`?

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem. I checked the network tab in chrome developer tools and all files are being sent back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your bootstrap.css isn't included properly. Try using the CDN or fixing the relative path of the css file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Project</title>
  ￼ <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="lib/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="public/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
```

Here's an example using only the CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/9nm5f0x9/

You don't need to include the bootstrap JS file as another commenter stated.

Comment: This doesn't work. For some reason the introduction of  `_.template` in my backbone view is the problem. I can't figure out why.

Comment: No worries, it should probably be https even if your server is using http.